# Mysql select ordinal

Tags: mysql, select, ordinal

Having a table named books which has the following structure:

```
╔════════════╦═══════════╦════════╗
║ LibraryId  ║  BookId   ║ Price  ║
╠════════════╬═══════════╬════════╣
║ 123        ║ 9001      ║ 10.99  ║
║ 123        ║ 9005      ║ 12.99  ║
║ 123        ║ 9006      ║ 7.99   ║
║ 124        ║ 8012      ║ 6.49   ║
║ 124        ║ 9001      ║ 3.19   ║
║ 124        ║ 9076      ║ 7.39   ║
╚════════════╩═══════════╩════════╝
```

How could I do a select that would return the full table, but additionally a field named Ordinal, that "counts" the number of books per library. The result should look something like:

```
╔════════════╦═══════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ LibraryId  ║  BookId   ║ Price  ║Ordinal ║
╠════════════╬═══════════╬════════╬════════╣
║ 123        ║ 9001      ║ 10.99  ║      1 ║
║ 123        ║ 9005      ║ 12.99  ║      2 ║
║ 123        ║ 9006      ║ 7.99   ║      3 ║
║ 124        ║ 8012      ║ 6.49   ║      1 ║
║ 124        ║ 9001      ║ 3.19   ║      2 ║
║ 124        ║ 9076      ║ 7.39   ║      3 ║
╚════════════╩═══════════╩════════╝════════╝
```

I have tried something like:

```
SET @var_record = 1;
SELECT *, (@var_record := @var_record + 1) AS Ordinal
FROM books;
```

But this will continue counting irrespective of the libraryId. I need something that will reset the ordinal every time the libraryId changes. I'd prefer a single query instead of procedures.

---

Test data sql scripts:

```
create temporary table books(libraryId int, bookId int, price double(4,2));
insert into books (libraryId, bookId, price) values (123, 9001, 10.99),(123, 9005, 10.99),(123, 9006, 10.99),(124, 8001, 10.99),(124, 9001, 10.99),(124, 9076, 10.99);
```

Comment: USE aggregated functions Count in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using variables and conditions you can reset the counter based on a condition (libraryId has changed). Mandatory to order by the column libraryId.

```
SELECT books.*, 
    if( @libId = libraryId, 
        @var_record := @var_record + 1, 
        if(@var_record := 1 and @libId := libraryId, @var_record, @var_record)
    ) AS Ordinal 
FROM books
JOIN (SELECT @var_record := 0, @libId := 0) tmp
ORDER BY libraryId;
```

The second if statement is used to group two assignments together and return @var_record.

```
if(@var_record := 1 and @libId := libraryId, @var_record, @var_record)
```

Comment: Whenever I see such MySQL solutions I shed a tear for everyone who can't use a database with real view functions ..

Comment: That's what happens when the architecture department is scared of stored procedures like it's black magic...

Comment: A SP wouldn't help the fundamental query in this case - it would be the equivalent or something outright procedural. The problem is just that MySQL lacks the ability to express such cleanly - and having to "accept" such a limitation is what makes me a little bit sad inside.

Answer (score 1):

This was obviously a very old question, but it's still found by Google so here's a modern answer for anyone who comes here looking for how to identify rows based on which sub-part (partition) of a result-set they fall in.

```
SELECT *
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column_0) AS ordinal
FROM (
VALUES
  ROW(123, 9001, 10.99)
, ROW(123, 9005, 12.99)
, ROW(123, 9006, 7.99)
, ROW(124, 8012, 6.49)
, ROW(124, 9001, 3.19)
, ROW(124, 9076, 7.39)
) AS t
;
```

Gives

```
+--------+--------+--------+-------+
|column_0|column_1|column_2|ordinal|
+--------+--------+--------+-------+
|123     |9001    |10.99   |1      |
|123     |9005    |12.99   |2      |
|123     |9006    |7.99    |3      |
|124     |8012    |6.49    |1      |
|124     |9001    |3.19    |2      |
|124     |9076    |7.39    |3      |
+--------+--------+--------+-------+
```

IMHO anyone coming from older versions of MySQL and working with databases regularly should familiarise themselves with window functions (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) as they unlock tremendous potential.

Incidentally, if you just wanted to count the number of books per library you'd simply do

```
SELECT column_0
     , COUNT(*) AS book_count
FROM ...
GROUP BY 1
;
```

Answer (score -3):

perhaps you can use aggregated functions

```
SELECT a.LibraryId, a.BookId, a.Price,
      (SELECT COUNT(b.BookId) FROM books b WHERE b.BookId = a.BookId AND b.LibraryId = a.LibraryId) AS Ordinal
FROM a.books
```

Comment: This returns 1,1,1,1,1 for all the "ordinals". Even if it was only group by LibraryId it would return 3, 3 and not what I asked. Please think the problem over and not respond quickly so that you are the first to post.

Comment: My bad, There will be a subquery that will be required. Let me change my answer.

Comment: The correction still does not work. It counts all grouped by libraryId, and bookId. This means that for the data in my example it returns 1,1,1,1,1,1 as ordinal.